# How to change the destination url if the site is visited from a redirection?

Tags: jquery, redirect

The same problem, but alternative questions:

- How redirect the user to another site when user visited the site from a redirect?
  or:
- How to add another url (excluding the destination) that is set automatically when the visitor would like to load the destination from a redirect? or:
- How to detect if the visitor came from a redirect and navigate him to another destination based on the certain source he came from?

For example:

xyz.co.nr is redirected to xyz.deviantart.com I would like to redirect the visitor to another site, not the "base" destination, so when the user types the xyz.co.nr it redirects him to google.com.

Is this possible with just JQuery?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to [so]! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: And probably you need to to it on the server side, you can't _redirect_  (i.e status code 301) on the client side using JS

Comment: @Alon Eitan I was afraid of that. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
// check if you came from a redirect
if ( document.referrer !== '' )
{
  //redirect to other site.
  document.location.href= "http://foo.bar"
}
```

Comment: `if ( document.referrer !== '' )` has to be that way? I mean, don't you put an url in it like: `if ( document.referrer == 'http://xyz.co.nr' )` ?

Comment: Sure if you'd wish to set a constant url. My example is for if you don't care who the 'referrer' was.